# Using @Reference to acquire service results in maven build warning

Tags: java, reference, annotations, osgi

I'm exploring using the OSGi R6 in declaring OSGi components and services. 
To get an instance of a service, we'd usually use @Reference, like below:

```
@Reference
PicklistService picklistService;
```

It looks trivial to make the change from R5 to R6 -- I just switched the import statements from `org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference` to `org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference`.

The only problem is that during a maven build, it gives off a warning:

```
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] C:\myapp\core\src\main\java\com\app\service\ServiceImpl.java:50: error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
[WARNING] @Reference
[WARNING] ^
```

The functionality works though, implying that I *am* getting a reference to the service that I need. I could live with that. But of course we'd want to minimize warnings like these. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using version 6 of the OSGi compendium spec jar?
In version 5 you could only use @Reference on methods in R6 it is also allowed on fields.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thank you!! That part wasn't apparent! I had set my sights on including the annotations `org.osgi.service.component.annotations` (with version 1.3.0) BUT I forgot to include `osgi.cmpn` version 6.0.0 in my pom file!

I did not notice it as my IDE didn't complain when I began using the new annotations. Thank you for this. :D